# Which components can be labelled as "BD" on a printed circuit board?

Tags: identification, component-failure

In the process of repairing some consumer electronics, I encountered some SMDs labelled `BD` on the silkscreen:

[image: blown out smd]

As this one has clearly blown, I'm interested in knowing what it could be.

Here is another component on the board, having the same label, that seems to be in better shape:

[image: SMD in good shape]

Note for people that might land here for a more general case: `BD` is a common abbreviation for "board".

Comment: Could it maybe stand for "Bead", i.e. Ferrite Bead? They are commonly named FB, but who knows.

Comment: We use `FB` for them (ferrite beads), `BD` seems unusual.

Comment: I found Waldo! Now where's that darn scroll...

Comment: It kind of looks some traces are fried too, so repairing might not be as trivial as replacing the component.

Comment: As for what BD stands for... Bad Designator? :) It's clearly a ferrite bead, I've seen FE or FB for those.

Comment: I'm pretty sure BD standard for "whatever **B**uddy, i **D**o what i want"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are ferrite BeaDs.

The one that died probably did so because of a failure (short) elsewhere.

Answer (score 9):

It's a ferrite bead by the look of it. Sometimes the reference used is FB and, I guess you can make it what you want if you are the designer.